# Helidon MP: How to send slf4j log messages to Kafka broker?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j2, slf4j, helidon

I am trying to send slf4j log messages in my Helidon MP application to a Kafka server that runs on port 9092. I have the following class as an example:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class Service {

  private final ConfigProvider configProvider;

  @Inject
  public Service(ConfigProvider configProvider) {
    this.configProvider = configProvider;
  }

  public String getString() {
    String msg = String.format("%s %s !", configProvider.getString());
    log.info("Entered getString() method");
    return msg;
  }
}
```

I also have a logging.xml file which specifies the Appender as KafkaAppender:

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Kafka name="KafkaAppender" topic="app-logs"
               syncSend="false">
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers"
                      value="localhost:9092"/>
        </Kafka>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="WARN"/> <!-- avoid recursive logging -->
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="KafkaAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However, when I run the application, I get the following errors:

```
2022-11-28 14:23:17,358 main ERROR No layout provided for KafkaAppender
2022-11-28 14:23:17,362 main ERROR Null object returned for Kafka in Appenders.
2022-11-28 14:23:17,364 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "KafkaAppender" for logger config "root"
```

Any suggestions on how to make KafkaAppender work with Helidon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Helidon does nothing special for logging. The only thing to note is that Helidon uses JUL (`java.util.logging`) for logging.

[KafkaAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/mom/kafka/KafkaAppender.html) is a Log4J2 appender, however you said "specify slf4j to send message to Kafka".

### 1. Setup the SLF4J to JUL bridge

See the [javadocs](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html).

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can setup the bridge either programmatically or by configuration.

##### Programmatically

```
import org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler;

SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

##### Using `logging.properties`

If you are using Helidon SE, you need to have code in your main class to load `logging.properties`. Helidon provides a utility for that, see below. If you are using Helidon MP, this is done for you automatically.

```
import io.helidon.common.LogConfig;

LogConfig.configureRuntime();
```

If you already have the statement above in your main method, you can setup the bridge by adding the following to your `logging.properties` file.

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
```

If you don't have a `logging.properties` file yet, create it under `src/main/resources` so that it is added to your project JAR.

### 2. Setup the SLF4J implementation

Import the Log4J2 bom in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Add the following dependencies to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

See the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html).

### 3. Configure Log4J2

See the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

The default path for a XML configuration file is `log4j2.xml`. Create the file at `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`

```
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Kafka name="KafkaAppender" topic="app-logs" syncSend="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%date %message" />
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers" value="localhost:9092"/>
        </Kafka>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="WARN"/> <!-- avoid recursive logging -->
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="KafkaAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Add the `kafka-clients` dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

Please note that there nothing specific to Helidon here apart from dependency version management and the utility provided to load `logging.properties`. You can use the same steps on any "plain" Java project.